# Plist encoding and decoding back to Dictionary [String:Decodable]

Tags: ios, swift, plist, codable

I want to be able to save Dictionary of type [String:Codable] to plist and recover back as same. I tried this but it throws errors:

```
  let dictionary:[String:Any] = ["point":CGPoint(1,1), "value": 10, "key" : "testKey"] 

   do { 
        let url = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("test.plist")
        try savePropertyList(dictionary, toURL: url)
        buildFromPlist(url)
      } catch {
        print(error)
    }
  


    private func savePropertyList(_ plist: Any, toURL url:URL) throws
   {
    let plistData = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: plist, format: .xml, options: 0)
    try plistData.write(to: url)
   }

  private func buildFromPlist(_ url:URL)
  {
       do {
          let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
          let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
          let dictionary = try decoder.decode([String:Decodable], from: data)
          NSLog("\(dictionary)")
      } catch {
           NSLog("Error decoding \(error)")
      }
   
    
   }
```

But I get build errors in decode function:

```
  Value of protocol type 'Decodable' cannot conform to 'Decodable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
```

I wonder how I read back the dictionary I saved to plist file?

EDIT: Even savePropertyList fails at runtime with objects such as CGPoint and CGAffineTransform with the error -

```
 "Property list invalid for format: 100 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Property list invalid for format: 100 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')}
```

I wonder how can we write Codable objects to plist and recover back?

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work because the type in the `decoder.decode` line **must** be a concrete type. And `[String:Decodable]` without trailing `.self` will throw another error.

The goal of the `Codable` protocol is to serialize custom structs or classes so make your dictionary a struct

```
struct MyType : Codable {
    let point : CGPoint
    let value : Int
    let key : String
}
```

and encode this. In the decoding part write

```
let item = try decoder.decode(MyType.self, from: data)
```

Comment: Ok I get that now, even save to property list fails with errors with objects complying to Codable/Decodable protocol. But then my point is I can not use a fixed struct MyType. Reason, MyType could change in future. If I save projects in plist format and always decode to MyType, then it may not be backward compatible at some point. I just want to write to plist and read and decode it back to dictionary.

Comment: If the types conform to `Codable` they do can be encoded to Property List. Of course you have to use `PropertyListEncoder`. If a custom struct cannot be used (what I doubt) you have to use traditional `PropertyListSerialization` and convert the non-compliant types to something Property List supports.

Comment: It gives me build time errors when I try to use PropertyListEncode().encode(plist) where plist is [String:Codable]

Comment: You can encode only concrete types which conform to `Encodable` but not the protocol itself.

Comment: Hmm, so what is the right solution to write and parse XML where there could be several versions of XML? In otherwords, there could be MyType1, MyType2 in future. The code needs to correctly detect the version of XML and then deserialise to appropriate type.

Comment: Add a logic for example a version number in `MyType`. Then first decode **only** this key and decode the type depending on its value.

Comment: How to do that, won't decoding to MyType fail if other parts of the structure is not aligned as per MyType. Also, can MyType hold MySubtypes each of which is compliant to Codable/Decodable?

Comment: You could create a minimal *check-struct* which contains only the version key. The decoder considers only the present keys. Yes `MyType` can contain other types conforming to `Codable`